# Función JavaScript capturada por onblur para procesar un PHP mediante AJAX no se ejecuta

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

En un formulario HTML cuando en un input se teclea un dato identificativo de una persona, al perder el foco se activa una función de JavaScript ("buscar") para hacer una búsqueda, se invoca a un modulo php mediante AJAX, pero NO REALIZA LA LLAMADA. Se envía el parámetro que necesita al archivo PHP que se encarga de realizar esto. Sé que el archivo PHP funciona correctamente porque he probado con la opción de "guardar" y se ejecuta correctamente sin problema y me cambia el registro en la base de datos. He incluido alertas para hacer el seguimiento, y en la opción de "buscar" no llega al php, el Ajax nunca se ejecuta.

Esta es la parte del código del formulario :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Programando Ando</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

<div class="cargando row">       
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="spinner-border text-primary" role="status">
      <span class="visually-hidden">Cargando...</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

  <div class="formulario row">
  <!-- INICIA LA COLUMNA -->
    <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
      <center><h1>DNI</h1></center>

      <form>
        <!--Campo Documento-->
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="doc">Dni</label></br>
          <input type="text" name="doc" class="form-control" id="doc" onblur="buscar();">
        </div>
        <!--Campo Nombre-->
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="nombre">Nombre </label>
            <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" id="nombre">
        </div>
        <!--Campo Dirección-->
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="dir">Dirección </label>
            <input type="text" name="dir" class="form-control" id="dir">
        </div>
        <!--Campo Teléfono-->
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="tel">Teléfono </label>
            <input type="text" name="tel" class="form-control" id="tel">
        </div>
        <!--Botones-->
        <center>
          <input type="button" value="ENVIAR" class="btn btn-success" name="btn_enviar" onclick="guardar();">
          <input type="button" value="CANCELAR" class="btn btn-danger" name="btn_cancelar" onclick="limpiar();">
        </center>
      </form>
      <div class="resultados"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.cargando').hide();
      });  

function buscar()
  {
    doc = $("#doc").val();
    alert('HTML/JAVA/AJAX_BUSCAR_DATOS : ' + doc + ' !!' );
    var parametros = 
    {
      "buscar": "1",
      "doc" : $("#doc").val()
    };

    $.ajax(
    {
      data:  parametros,
      url:   '00_codigos_php.php',
      type:  'post',
      beforeSend: function() 
      {
        $('.formulario').hide();
        $('.cargando').show();
        
      }, 
      error: function()
      {alert("Error_buscar_datos");},
      complete: function() 
      {
        $('.formulario').show();
        $('.cargando').hide();
       
      },
      success:  function (valores) 
      {
        if(valores.existe=="1") //Aqui usamos la variable que NO use en el vídeo
        {
          $("#nombre").val(valores.nombre);
          $("#dir").val(valores.direccion);
          $("#tel").val(valores.telefono);
        }
        else
        {
          alert("HTML_El propietario no existe, ¡Crealo!")
        }

      }
    }) 
  }

function limpiar()
  {
    $("#doc").val("");
    $("#nombre").val("");
    $("#dir").val("");
    $("#tel").val("");
  }

function guardar()
  {
    var parametros = 
    {
      "guardar": "1",
      "doc" : $("#doc").val(),
      "nombre" : $("#nombre").val(),
      "tel" : $("#tel").val(),
      "dir" : $("#dir").val()
    };
    $.ajax(
    {
      data:  parametros,
      url:   '00_codigos_php.php',
      type:  'post',
      beforeSend: function() 
      {
        $('.formulario').hide();
        $('.cargando').show();
        
      }, 
      error: function()
      {alert("Error");},
      complete: function() 
      {
        $('.formulario').show();
        $('.cargando').hide();
       
      },
      success:  function (mensaje) 
      {$('.resultados').html(mensaje);}
    }) 
    limpiar();
  }
</script>

Esta es la parte del código del php : 

    <!--             00_codigos_php.php             -->
    <?php
    include "conexion.php"; 
    if ($con->connect_error) {
        die("Connection fallida: " . $con->connect_error);}  
    
    $doc = $_POST['doc'];
    $funcion1 = $_POST['buscar'];
    $funcion2 = $_POST['guardar'];
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
    alert('PHP_INICIO=> 00_codigos_php.php :  $doc _/_ $funcion1 _/_ $funcion2 !');
    </script>";
    
    if(isset($_POST['buscar']))
         { 
            echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                alert('PHP_BUSCAR=> 00_codigos_php.php (BUSCAR):  $doc !');
                    </script>";
    
            $doc = $_POST['doc'];
            $valores = array();
            $valores['existe'] = "0";
            //CONSULTAR
              $resultados = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM PRU_Maesocios WHERE dni = '$doc'");
              while($consulta = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados))
              {
                $valores['existe'] = "1"; 
                $valores['nombre'] = $consulta['nombre'];
                $valores['direccion'] = $consulta['direccion'];
                $valores['telefono'] = $consulta['telefono'];           
              }
              sleep(1);
              $valores = json_encode($valores);
                echo $valores;
        }
    
    if(isset($_POST['guardar']))
        {       
            $doc = $_POST['doc'];
            $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
            $dir = $_POST['dir'];
            $tel = $_POST['tel'];
            $existe = "0";
            
            echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                alert('PHP_GUARDAR=> 00_codigos_php.php :  $doc $nombre $dir!');
                    </script>";
    
            //CONSULTAR
              $resultados = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM PRU_Maesocios WHERE dni = '$doc'");
              while($consulta = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados))
              {
                $existe = "1";
              }
    
              if($existe=="1")
              {
                //actualizar
                 $_UPDATE_SQL="
                   UPDATE PRU_Maesocios Set
                        nombre='$nombre',
                        direccion='$dir',
                        telefono='$tel'
                    WHERE doc='$doc'"; 
                mysqli_query($con,$_UPDATE_SQL); 
                echo "<b>Dato Actualizado</b>";
              }
              else
              {
                //crear uno nuevo
                mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO PRU_Maesocios 
                (doc,nombre,direccion,telefono) 
                values 
                ('$doc','$nombre','$dir','$tel')");
                echo "Propietario Agregado";
              }
    
        }
    include "cerrarconexion.php"; 
    ?>
```

Comment: que pasa si haces un `console.log(valores)` dentro del `success`?

Comment: El success no es el problema, ya que no llega al php, si miras el  00_codigos_php.php, nada mas realizar la conexión hay una alerta, con independencia de la función que se ha llamado y en el caso de buscar no llega a este módulo, por lo que NO se ecuta.

Comment: En principio esta todo mal, no mezcles PHP con JAVASCRIPT, ya esta utilizando AJAX, separa tus scripts para identificar el error. Si pretendes enviar los valores a la misma pagina por ahí puede estar el error, también al comprobar la llegada de dicho parámetro debes verificarlo con el mismo nombre con el que lo envia Ajax en (isset). Añadiendo replique lo que pude de la función **Onblur** y si funciona, el detalle lo haz de tener el PHP que no recibe de forma correcta el parámetro enviado por Ajax.

Comment: Revisa si estas recibiendo el $_POST en PHP, segun recuerdo, no puedes solo enviar un objeto JS como post, tienes que serializarlo o parsearlo luego en PHP, o desde el JS mandarlo como formdata

Comment: No hay mezcla de Java con PHP,  la parte de Java está en el formulario HTML, y es donde se incluye la función con código ajax para realizar una llamada asíncrona a un elemento php. El problema está en que la llamada a la función "buscar", cuando se ejecuta, le llega correctamente la petición, levanta la alerta que he puesto para comprobar que es llamada correctamente, pero en ese momento ya no realiza la ejecución del módulo php.

Comment: He comprobado que en el onblur, haciendo una prueba, si en vez de llamar a "buscar" cambio por  "grabar" funciona correctamente.. ¿Donde está el problema?. No lo se, por eso pido ayuda y colaboración. Muchas gracias.